# jq query not working in expected behaviour

Tags: json, jq

```
{
  "data": {
    "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID": "topsecret",
    "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": "s3cr3t"
  },
  "metadata": {
    "created_time": "2022-09-16T06:49:11.45818Z",
    "deletion_time": "",
    "destroyed": false,
    "version": 23
  }
}
```

I've above data and I want my input as:

```
"data": {
    "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID": "topsecret",
    "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": "s3cr3t"
  }
```

jq query like this `jq .data file.json` is only giving me output like this:

```
{
  "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID": "topsecret",
  "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": "s3cr3t"
 }
```

Please help.

Comment: Your desired output is not valid JSON (object braces are missing). Using `jq '{data}' file.json` will give you valid JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you want invalid json? You can preserve the key if you enclose it in curly braces, e.g.:

```
jq '{ data }'
```

Output:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID": "topsecret",
    "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": "s3cr3t"
  }
}
```

Note that the above is a shorthand for `{ "data": .data }`